# How to handle LiveData items in onResume - onPause state only?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

[Documentation says:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html)

> LifecycleOwner is considered as active, if its state is STARTED or RESUMED.

But what if I want it to be active if the state is RESUMED only? For example, show some fancy animation when user back on screen.
Is there a way to do this using only LiveData?

For now, I'm checking state when an event comes and if state is not RESUMED, 
I'm caching it to proceed in onResume method. That doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation provided by Google, this is the only way to do that, at least for now (version alpha3 as I'm writing this answer). I think what you are doing here (distinguishing between stared and resumed state) is quite an edge case and Android Architecture Components are designed to be a generic "fit all" library.

Answer (score 0):

You can also subclass LiveData or MutableLiveData to get the behavior you want, which will be easier if you want this behavior in more than one place.